# Window will not close

Tags: repair, windows, winterizing

[image]I have a single hung vinyl window that I can't get to close all the way.  The the building was built in 2007 and I assume the window is that old. Nothing appears to be blocking the track. Can this be fixed or should I look into replacing the window.

picture of the small gap at the bottom of the window
[image]

Comment: have a really good look at the problem and describe it in great detail ... the picture shows something that you neglected to mention

Comment: There is a 1/8 inch gap between the bottom rail and the frame of the window. The catch does not engage. It feels like something is blocking the window from closing. When I inspected the window I could not find anything that might be blocking it from closing.

Comment: you seem to be missing the fact that the window is at an angle to the frame

Comment: The picture might make it look that way. However the 1/8th inch gap runs along the full window. I'm going to add a new picture.

Comment: Check the track on which the window slides, and check that the catch at the **top** of the window** is not hitting an obstruction.

Comment: I tried to take the window out to look at tracks and sides of the window. One of the take-out clips is missing and the other one is broken. I'm going to put new take-out clips in and see if I can get the window out.

Comment: It appears that I have broken channel balance. I'm going to try to find the right replacement part and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window had a broken channel balance. I was able to order parts and replace both channel balances. I replaced both since it seemed like I should but maybe I could have just replaced the broken one.

How to replace a non-tilt window channel balance:

https://youtu.be/u4g8Z8jkwTk